# deleteFileAfterSend Laravel response doesn't delete file in tests

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I an have laravel 5.5 App.
I'm trying to make a test for download PDF with laravel snappy.

So far I have in my **CheckTest.php** one function:

```
public function testPrintCheck(){

   $check = $this->createCheck();
   $route ="/api/checks/print/$check->id";
   $response = $this->get($route);
   $this->assertEquals($response->headers->get('content-type') , 'application/pdf');
   $response->assertStatus(200);
 }
```

In my controller I have:

```
public function printCheck(Request $request, Check $check){
   $pdf = \PDF::loadView("pdf.check");
   $file= storage_path(). "/app/checks/$check->id.pdf";
   $pdf->save($file);
   $headers = array(
      'Content-Type: application/pdf'
   );
   return response()->download($file, "check_n_$check->id.pdf", $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true)->setStatusCode(200);

}
```

The current test works but I expect to delete file that I have create after download (with **deleteFileAfterSend(true)**) , but the file is not deleted.

So if I add the assert that file not exist it fails.

Comment: What is the need for the `true` argument in `->deleteFileAfterSend()`. And what are you using `->setStatusCode(200)'? This may be causing the issue.

Comment: the arguments is needed in the function , true o false for know if I should delete or no, and setStatusCode, set the status code of response to 200, and no, I tried to delete setStatusCode but it not works

Comment: i can't find deleteFileAfterSend() in laravel snappy

Comment: Is not a laravel snappy method, but a response() method.

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 4):

There is a possible solution to this according to the issue created not so long ago on github:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36286

Working on Laravel 8.24

Basically we need to force sending file contents, which then triggers file deletion

```php
public function test(): void
{
    $response = $this->get('url/to/download');

    // Here the file is not deleted yet

    $response->sendContent();

    // Here the file is deleted
}
```